# Convert Array to html table in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array generated by an API i use a cpanel hosting with php 5.6.

I tried a lot of combination but is not working

The array are generated by emag marketplace api.

The code looks like

```html
Array
(
    [isError] => 
    [messages] => Array
        (
        )

    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [vendor_name] => WISE COMPUTER SRLD
                    [id] => 2003677675
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [date] => 2017-05-21 10:55:18
                    [payment_mode] => RAMBURS
                    [payment_mode_id] => 1
                    [delivery_mode] => CURIER RO
                    [observation] => 
                    [status] => 4
                    [payment_status] => 0
                    [customer] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 994041
                            [mkt_id] => 994041
                            [name] => Cristina Manuela Dancas
                            [company] => Cristina Manuela Dancas
                            [gender] => 
                            [phone_1] => 0743073616
                            [phone_2] => 
                            [phone_3] => 
                            [registration_number] => 
                            [code] => 
                            [email] => 
                            [billing_name] => 
                            [billing_phone] => 
                            [billing_country] => RO
                            [billing_suburb] => Bucuresti
                            [billing_city] => Sectorul 1
                            [billing_locality_id] => 2
                            [billing_street] => Str. Aviator Sanatescu nr. 57, parter, Ap1
                            [billing_postal_code] => 
                            [shipping_country] => RO
                            [shipping_suburb] => Bucuresti
                            [shipping_city] => Sectorul 1
                            [shipping_locality_id] => 2
                            [shipping_postal_code] => 
                            [shipping_contact] => Cristina Manuela Dancas
                            [shipping_phone] => 0743073616
                            [created] => 2017-05-21 10:55:19
                            [modified] => 2017-05-21 10:56:21
                            [bank] => 
                            [iban] => 
                            [legal_entity] => 0
                            [fax] => 
                            [is_vat_payer] => 1
                            [liable_person] => 
                            [shipping_street] => Str. Aviator Sanatescu nr. 57, parter, Ap1
                        )
```

I what to use php to convert in a HTML table.

Need some help. If you need more information please leave a message.

Comment: _...I tried a lot of combination but is not working..._ Post 1 of your best approaches and describe what errors/issues you are facing there

Comment: I would suggest just looping over the contents of the array and generating an HTML string that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is my quick solution to make a HTML table from a PHP array.
The essence is although, that a two-dimensional array, makes into a table that makes sense. Your array seems to be more complex, so converting into a useful table will probably take a bit more effort.

```php
    $data = array(  array("ID","Firstname","Lastname","Phone"),
                    array("1","John","Jenkins","+91375953"),
                    array("2","Eduard","Kenny","+7244277"),
                    array("3","Anita","Beaumont","+427427427"),
                    array("4","Wanda","Wade","+274274247"),
                    array("4","Sarah","Colon","+835835"),
                );


    echo '<table border="1">';
    foreach($data as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $cell) {
            echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```